# program stop working when free malloc memory

Tags: c, memory, operating-system, malloc, page-tables

I initialized a global variable page_table using malloc like below. Each element inside is a struct:

```
page* page_table;

void init_clock(FILE* fd,int num_of_frames){
    total_frames = num_of_frames;
    fp = fd;
    page_table = malloc(sizeof(page)*num_of_frames);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<num_of_frames;i++){
        page_table[i].page_number = -1;
        page_table[i].dirty = 0;
        page_table[i].valid = 0;
        page_table[i].referenced = 0;
        page_table[i].virtual_time = -1;
    }
}
```

In my another method, each time it will generate a page struct. If it is already in the page table, it will be updated. If it is not in the page table, but there is available space, it will be added. Otherwise, evict a page from the page table.

```
void execute_clock(){
    int available_frames = total_frames;
    int next = 0;   // next location in the page table
    int page_to_examine = 0;  // next page that will be evicted
    unsigned int address;
    char mode;
    while(fscanf(fp,"%x %c", &address, &mode) != EOF){
        printf("%08x,%c\n",address,mode);
        page new_access = {address>>12,1,mode=='W',1,mem_access};
        /* add the frame into the frame array */
        int location_in_table = already_in_table(new_access);
        if( location_in_table != -1){       // if page is already in table, update stats
            page_table[location_in_table].referenced = 1;
            if(new_access.dirty) page_table[location_in_table].dirty = 1;
//            printf("hit\n");
        }
        else if(available_frames){           // if there are spaces available, add directly
            page_table[next] = new_access;
            available_frames--;
            next = (next+1)%total_frames;
            page_faults++;
//            printf("page fault - no eviction\n");
        }
        else{                             // evict page out of table
            /* find the page to evict */
            int found = 0;
            while(!found){
                if (page_table[page_to_examine].referenced == 0){
                    found = 1;
                }
                else page_table[page_to_examine].referenced = 0;
                page_to_examine = (page_to_examine+1)%total_frames;
            }
            /* evict the page */
            int evict = page_to_examine == 0?total_frames-1:page_to_examine-1;
            if(page_table[evict].dirty == 1){
                disk_writes++;
                printf("evict dirty %08x\n",page_table[evict].page_number);
            }else{
                printf("evict clean %08x\n",page_table[evict].page_number);
            }
            page_table[page_to_examine-1] = new_access;
            page_faults++;
        }
        mem_access++;
        print_table();
    }
}
```

My problem is after running the above code, when I tried to free the memory using:

```
   void exit_clock(){
    free(page_table);
}
```

The program just stopped running. The error is:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./main: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x00000000006                                                                                                                                   02010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x34ff676166]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x34ff678ca3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(fclose+0x14d)[0x34ff6667cd]
./main[0x400d7a]
./main[0x40075f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x34ff61ed1d]
./main[0x400629]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:1a 2136211636                         /afs/pi                                                                                                                                   tt.edu/home/z/i/ziz19/private/cs1550/project3/main
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:1a 2136211636                         /afs/pi                                                                                                                                   tt.edu/home/z/i/ziz19/private/cs1550/project3/main
00602000-00623000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
34fee00000-34fee20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 127                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   ld-2.12.so
34ff01f000-34ff020000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 127                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   ld-2.12.so
34ff020000-34ff021000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 127                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   ld-2.12.so
34ff021000-34ff022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
34ff600000-34ff78b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 131                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   libc-2.12.so
34ff78b000-34ff98a000 ---p 0018b000 fd:00 131                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   libc-2.12.so
34ff98a000-34ff98e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 131                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   libc-2.12.so
34ff98e000-34ff98f000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 131                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   libc-2.12.so
34ff98f000-34ff994000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3505a00000-3505a16000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 609                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3505a16000-3505c15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 609                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3505c15000-3505c16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 609                            /lib64/                                                                                                                                   libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7ffff7fd3000-7ffff7fd6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffea000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsysca                                                                                                                                   ll]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm not sure why this problem would happen. I'm assigning local page struct to the page_table only in the execute_clock method. Even local variables are destroyed, that shouldn't affect me from free malloc memory.

Comment: I'd look into valgrind to find bad memory accesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the index of the circular array that I'm not updating correctly.